# Getting The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime Exception

Tags: c#, do-while

This is part of my code:

```
DateTime answer;

DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    do {

        if (years / planetyeardata[0] > 1)
        {


            answer = today.AddDays(87.97 * (1 - (days / 87.97 - (days / 87.97))));
            mnbd.Text = answer.ToString();
            today = answer;
        }
        else
        {

            answer = today.AddDays(87.97 * (1 - days / 87.97));    // + (224.7 * (1 - days / 224.7) * 24 * 3600 * 1000));

            today = answer;
            mnbd.Text = answer.ToString();

        }
    } while (today <= answer);
```

When I don't have the do-while statement around the if-statement, the bit of code to work out "answer" is working fine. But with the do-while I am getting this error.

I basically want to keep performing the calculation for "answer" until its value is higher than current date.

Comment: I would like to add when I tried without the do-while loop, I had the 
DateTime today = DateTime.Today; inside of the if-statement

Answer (score 0):

So here's a little analysis of your code.

In short - your do-while list will never end looping and in all but one scenario you'll either hit a minimum or maximum `DateTime` value upon which you'll get the exception.

The long version - your do-while list has 2 parts - one in `if` and one in `else` block. Since the condition is `years / planetyeardata[0] > 1` and nothing in your loop is changing `years` or `planetyeardata`, this condition could be considered a constant. So basically, your do-while loop will either always go to `if` block or always to `else` block.

If it's entering an `if` block, the expression `answer = today.AddDays(87.97 * (1 - (days / 87.97 - (days / 87.97))));` will always make `answer = today.AddDays(87.97)`, the reason being that `(days / 87.97 - (days / 87.97))` is always 0. Immediatelly after, you're setting `today = answer`. Since you're always setting `today` to be equal to `answer`, you'll never break `while (today <= answer)` condition. On the other hand your dates will always increase by 87.97 days and will at some time be greater than `DateTime.MaxValue` which will throw an exception.

If it's entering an `else` block, you have an expression `answer = today.AddDays(87.97 * (1 - days / 87.97));`. Depending on `days` value, you have 3 possible outcomes:

1. `days < 87.97` - in this case `(1 - days / 87.97)` will always be greater than zero because of which your dates will gradually increase until you get to `DateTime.MaxValue` which will throw an exception
2. `days == 87.97` - in this case `(1 - days / 87.97)` will always be equal to zero because of which your dates will never change and never leave the do-while block
3. `days > 87.97` - in this case `(1 - days / 87.97)` will always be less than zero because of which your date will gradually decrease until you get to `DateTime.MinValue` which will throw an exception

Since you're immediately after setting `today = answer`, you'll never break `while (today <= answer)` condition and your loop will never stop until you get the exception.

So, generally, your `while` condition is always fulfilled and the code inside the block will always get out of bounds of available `DateTime` values with one possible outcome (`days == 87.97` in `else` block) where your dates will always remain the same and never leave the do-while block.

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime Structure has a Minimum value of 1/1/0001 and a maximum value of 12/31/9999

The code in your loop is attempting to add a number of days that is making `today` go outside of this range.

You can check for the overflow and handle the exception accordingly:

```
DateTime answer;
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
do
{

    if (years / planetyeardata[0] > 1)
    {



        var daysToAdd = (1 - (days / 87.97 - (days / 87.97)));
        if (daysToAdd > 0 && DateTime.MaxValue.Subtract(today).TotalDays > daysToAdd)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Can't add {0} days to {1}", daysToAdd, today));
        if (daysToAdd < 0 && today.Subtract(DateTime.MinValue).TotalDays > daysToAdd)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Can't add {0} days to {1}", daysToAdd, today));

        answer = today.AddDays(87.97 *daysToAdd );
        mnbd.Text = answer.ToString();
        today = answer;
    }
    else
    {
        var daysToAdd = (1 - (days / 87.97 - (days / 87.97)));
        if (daysToAdd > 0 && DateTime.MaxValue.Subtract(today).TotalDays > daysToAdd)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Can't add {0} days to {1}", daysToAdd, today));
        if (daysToAdd < 0 && today.Subtract(DateTime.MinValue).TotalDays> daysToAdd)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Can't add {0} days to {1}", daysToAdd, today));

        answer = today.AddDays(87.97 * (1 - days / 87.97));    // + (224.7 * (1 - days / 224.7) * 24 * 3600 * 1000));

        today = answer;
        mnbd.Text = answer.ToString();

    }
} while (today <= answer);
```